# JTextField no size?

Tags: java, swing

Currently my `JTextField` component is sizing to what appears to be 0. I have attempted to `setPreferredSize`, `setSize(new Dimension)`, added columns & removed the anchor with `GridBagConstraints`. Nothing has worked thus far. Here is my code:

```
private void createPayFrame() {

    JFrame payFrame = new JFrame();
    payFrame.setSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
    payFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    payFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel payment = new JLabel("<html>Your bill has been generated. It is located in your "
            + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\eclipse-workspace\\Turbo Team directory</html>");
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JTextField payField = new JTextField(10);
    payField.setToolTipText("Enter in the amount due here");

    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.ABOVE_BASELINE;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,20,0);
    payFrame.add(payment, gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    payFrame.add(payField, gbc);

    payFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is what it looks like when I run the code: 
[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fill for the textfield

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why wasn't it doing this automatically?

Comment: because NONE is the default fill which leaves the component at its initial size. You could also pack the frame to allow components to take their preferred sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with GridBagLayout when the JTextField was too large to display.  Have you tried with less columns?  Maybe try to start at `new JTextField(1)` and work your way up to see if it works at smaller lengths.